# Bootstrap Grid Column Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I've got a bootstrap grid that I'm using on my site which I'm having some resizing issues with.

There's some columns that I want to disappear on the small screen size but the stacking of columns is now broken as a result.

what is the best way to hide these three columns #spider4, #spider5, #spider6 without breaking the columns and rows.

Thanks.

```css
<style type="text/css">
    */p{
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        background: #dbdfe5;
    }
    img.image-4-3.home-services-images {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
    
    #spider2 {
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
        #spider7 {
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
        #spider9 {
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 0px) {
#spider2, #spider7, #spider9 {
            margin-top: 0px !important;
}
        #spider4, #spider5, #spider6 {
            display: none;   
        }
}
</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Multi-Column Grid Layout for All Devices</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <!-- Open the output in a new blank tab (Click the arrow next to "Show Output" button) and resize the window to understand how the Bootstrap responsive grid system works. -->
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
                        <div id="spider1" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
                        <div id="spider2" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider3" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider4" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider5" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" /></div>
                        <div id="spider6" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider7" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider8" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider9" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Hidden-xs, Hidden-lg, Hidden-sm & Hiddem-md classes to hide in respective viewports.
or you can use visible-lg, visible-sm, visible-xs, visible-md

To make alignment remove this CSS classes

```
  #spider2 {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
    #spider7 {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
    #spider9 {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

---

**Corrected Code:**

```css
<style type="text/css">
    */p{
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        background: #dbdfe5;
    }
    img.image-4-3.home-services-images {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
    
  
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 0px) {
#spider2, #spider7, #spider9 {
            margin-top: 0px !important;
}
        #spider4, #spider5, #spider6 {
            display: none;   
        }
}
</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Multi-Column Grid Layout for All Devices</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <!-- Open the output in a new blank tab (Click the arrow next to "Show Output" button) and resize the window to understand how the Bootstrap responsive grid system works. -->
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
                        <div id="spider1" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
                        <div id="spider2" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider3" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider4" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider5" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" /></div>
                        <div id="spider6" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider7" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider8" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
                        <div id="spider9" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
<h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues you've probably got is your media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 0px)
```

Unless you've customised the defaults, bootstrap ships with breakpoints at 768, 992 and 1200px's.

So you probably should have used:

```
@media(max-width:991px)
```

Having said that, you could have just used the "available classes" to hide those columns for those devices. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

eg; `"hidden-xs"` and `"hidden-sm"` used in combination will hide that column on all devices less that 992px wide.

In regards to the `"clearfix"` div, you should insert this after every second visible divs for "`xs"` and `"sm"` (so you've got to pretend like 4, 5 and 6 don't exist) and after every third div for `"md"` and `"lg"`

Also, when you define a grid size for a breakpoint like `"col-md-4"` you dont' need to define it for the next size up if it is also 4 columns.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
```

is the equivalent of

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
```

Here's a working example of your problem, i've changed the body colour at each breakpoint just for demo purposes.

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/WwPzxO